# How the info button dark style should look like?

Tags: ios7, uibutton

I use the system type of info button dark for creating an instance from the UIButton cluster. It looks the same as for the info light type: the encircled "i" character and all coloured depending on a tint colour property.

Shouldn't the dark button style provide a solid circle instead and filled completely but the "i" character inside?